How to query the associated node related to a node in surrealdb？
In this scenario, we need to query an A node instance and its associated entire topology graph. We can use the Cypher query language of the Neo4j graph database to implement this requirement. Suppose we have the following nodes and relationships
1、A node instance (e.g., AInstance)
2、B node instances associated with the A node instance (e.g., BInstance)
3、C node instances associated with the B node instance (e.g., CInstance)
The relationships between nodes can be represented as:
1、AInstance --(Relationship1)--> BInstance
2、BInstance --(Relationship2)--> CInstance
We can use the following Cypher query to search for an A instance that meets the given conditions and return its associated entire topology graph:
MATCH (a:AInstance {property: 'value'})-[:Relationship1]-(b:BInstance)-[:Relationship2]-(c:CInstance)
RETURN a, b, c;

My questions are as follows:
1、How to use surrealql to solve this problem
2、What should I do if I want to filter the node attributes

Do check out the SurrealDB for Neo4j developers guide which shows the syntax mapping between Cypher and SurrealQL for similar queries.

